# ##[error]No manifest file(s) matching <file> was found. Azure release pipeline error

Tags: azure, pipeline

I got this error in release of azure pipeline.
I created an azure pipeline which builds a dockerfile. When I am creating release-pipeline to deploy that image to Azure AKS, it shows this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVtTm.png)

```html
trigger:
- main

# resources:
# - repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: '45a6d593-c59d-433c-8bcf-3dca94701b0f'
  imageRepository: 'todoapp'
  containerRegistry: 'dostonacr.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

pool:
  name: default

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
          latest
    # - task: CopyFiles@2
    #   inputs:
    #     SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
    #     Contents: '**'
    #     TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    #     condition: succeededOrFailed()
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)/'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'
```

This my pipeline how looks like.

Answer (score -1):

May be the  that you are referring to is not available

Comment: Too generic answer, not really useful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).